# Adding blank space in angular 8 html page issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Whenever I try to add blank space it will go to Next Line

Example
My Queue //In this case it goes to Queue in next Line

Below is `componant.ts`

```
self.queueList.push({ 'encryt': CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(item, self.ecrykey.trim()).toString(), 'value': item });
```

In Html page//

```
<div class="panel" style="text-align:left; width: 15;">           
            <div *ngFor="let item of queueList">
                <a [routerLink]="['/navbar',{queue: item.encryt }] ">{{item.value | titlecase}}</a>            
            </div>
        </div>
```

//Quelist contain strings SC is attached , MyQueue(10),Intro(5)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in your CSS